# how to configure windows login to get OTP as password

Tags: authentication, windows, java, one-time-password

I searched a little and understand that its possible,But i couldn't find any clue of how to do it.Also can i use any server that works or it must be something like SafeNet's blackShield server?
Also the only way to use OTP as password for login in windows was in offline mode according to some documents i saw.is there a way to use it as default?

PS: I'm a developer who works on a AAA application.We have a server for authentication.

**Edit**
What i'm looking for is not how to develop it.I'm looking for architecture model or a document that i couldn't find about what it needs and how to integrate the authentication server whether its developed by my company or any other company with windows.problem is i don't know what to look for.

Comment: I actually think you would be better off on one of the other SE sites since this is more about development of a tool than about Information Security. ServerFault or StackOverflow. It is certainly possible but the main info is about integration via 3rd party products such as ROHOS or OneLogin.

Comment: I do agree with Julian, this question would better fit in StackOverflow. But currently it would be too broad. Have a look to [GINA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication) for pre-Vista versions and [credential providers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647(v=vs.85).aspx) and read that [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228499/documentation-for-creating-a-custom-credential-provider-in-windows). You should be able to start something and then ask more precise questions on SO.

Comment: @JulianKnight i saw this question and it didn't have the answer that fit my problem so i thought its not bad to ask this in SO [One Time Passwords. Using OTP at Windows, Ubuntu and internet sites](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/one-time-passwords-using-otp-at-windows-ubuntu-and-internet-sites)

Comment: No problem. It can be hard to know which site to use. I don't have a full answer. However, you've long been able to replace the standard login with a custom one, the method has changed but it is still available. Any method you choose should be able to work both on and off-line but that is up to the custom login software. So you can certainly integrate your product, I recommend following Serge's leads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution i found for this problem was to add a Credential Provider (CP) for windows to change the authentication type to OTP and then use Raduis to connect it to the OTP server or any autentication server that you want.
to be more clear what thing you need for this is the Credential provider.its conditions depends on you.
P.S : the CP i used was the PGina.